# vba ie navigate multiple sessions

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm using VBA to access IE through this website, but there's an issue that I can't figure out.  The webpage tracks whether there are multiple open window sessions and logs me out when I start to navigate to another window. Is there a way to continue the session and navigate back to the previous page without disconnecting?

As a side note, the webpage is not a public domain.

Here's what I have that doesn't work:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True

'code to Login to webpage went here

Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById("txtFileNumber").Value = "12345678"
doc.getElementById("cmdSearch").Click

Do While .Busy Or .READYSTATE <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim requested as Object
Dim trans As String
Set requested = doc.getElementById("TransitLink")
If requested.isDisabled = False Then
    trans = requested.href
End If

IE.navigate trans ' <----msgbox comes up "Multiple sessions not allowed"
```

Here's a part of the HTML code if this helps at all.

```
<a id="TransitLink" title="In Transit" class="button" onClick="inqPopups[7] = window.open(this.href, 'popup7', 'WIDTH=350,HEIGHT=250,scrollbars,resizable,status,toolbar=yes'); (document.getElementById('txtFileNumber')).focus(); (document.getElementById('txtFileNumber')).select(); inqPopups[7].focus(); return false;" href="TransactionInTransit.aspx?... style="color:Blue;">In Transit</a>

    var inqPopups = new Array();
    function closeSubWindow() {
        for (var i = 0; i < inqPopups.length; i++) {
            if (inqPopups[i] && !inqPopups[i].closed) {
                inqPopups[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `With IE` and do all the code and the `End With`

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

Wtih IE
.Visible = True

'code to Login to webpage went here

Set doc = IE.document
doc.getElementById("txtFileNumber").Value = "12345678"
doc.getElementById("cmdSearch").Click
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim requested As Object
Dim trans As String
Set requested = doc.getElementById("TransitLink")
If requested.isDisabled = False Then
    trans = requested.href
End If

.navigate trans  


' Rest of code

.Quit ' close ie window
End With      'once done with IE window
```

Since you have `Set IE = New` it creates a new instance of IE every time. So to keep it all in one window you have to use the `With IE` `End With`method.